# iOS 8 hide the colored top bar alert when apps are actively using your location in the background

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I want to hide the colored top bar alert when apps are actively using your location in the background, how can i do it?

Comment: Are you asking as a user or do you wish to do this programmatically in your app?

Comment: Dunno, but I suspect you can't. Isn't the very purpose of that alert to make sure background apps can't use your location without you knowing about it? Hiding it would defeat that purpose, no?

Comment: I want to hide it programatically in my app...

Answer (score 0):

use `requestAlwaysAuthorization` instead of `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`.